# Decomposition of a vector in Pseudo-Euclidian space into to form $x = \lambda z + y$, where $(z,y) = 0$ and $\lambda = -(x,z) $

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *Linear Algebra* by Werner Greub, at page 284, it is given that

> More generally let us consider an n-dimensional pseudo-Euclidean space
>   with index -1. Then every fixed time-like unit vector z determines an
>   orthogonal decomposition of E into an (n-1)-dimensional subspace
>   consisting of space-like vectors and the 1-dimensional subspace
>   generated by z. In fact, every vector $x \in E$ can be uniquely
>   decomposed in the form $$x = \lambda z + y \quad (z,y) = 0 ,$$ where
>   the scalar $\lambda = - (x,z).$

I can understand (almost) why we can do such a composition because if we take an orthogonal basis, in the decomposition of $x$ into that basis, we collapse the space like vectors part to $y$, and the rest is like as it is, and it is obvious that $z$ and $y$ should be orthogonal.

However, the problem that I'm having is that **why is $\lambda = -(x,z)$** ?

Comment: Compute the scalar product $(z,y)$ and note that, with this value of $\lambda$ you get $(z,y) = 0$. The minus sign is needed because you are in a pseudo-Euclidean space with index $-1$.

Comment: @Klaramun by definition $(z,z) = -1$ and the $||z|| = 1$ since it is a **fixed time-like unit vector.**

Comment: Yes I have edited my answer.

Comment: @Klaramun if I expand $y$ in terms of the orthogonal basis of $n-1$ dimensional subspace which $z$ is mutually orthogonal, I don't need such a condition.

Comment: Why you can expand $y$ in terms of the orthogonal basis of $n-1$ dimensional subspace, orthogonal to $z$? Why $y$ doesn't have any $z$ component? The point is that $y$ is exactly a generic vector $x$ substracting to it the $z$ component of such a vector, and this is achieved in the way $x - \lambda z$, with this specified lambda if you want this new vector $y = x - \lambda z$ to be in the $n-1$ dimensional subspace orthogonal to $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since:

- $(z,z)=-1$;
- $(z,y)=0$;
- $x=\lambda z+y$

you have\begin{align}(x,z)&=(\lambda z+y,z)\\&=\lambda(z,z)+(y,z)\\&=-\lambda.\end{align}